# authentication with Firebase 3.0 in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Because of firebase have upgraded to version 3.0 and i need to migrate to the new version, a problem arose as the authentication of my node server. The code is this

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "<minha apiKey>",
  authDomain: "<meu domínio de autenticação>",
  databaseURL: "<url do banco>",
  storageBucket: "<minha storageBucket>",
  serviceAccount: "<nome do arquivo gerado pela conta de serviço>.json"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

When running npm start, the following error appears:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid. 
This   usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized
correctly. 
Make sure your apiKey and databaseURL match the values provided for your 
app at 'https://console.firebase.google.com/', or if you're using 
a service account, make sure it's authorized to access the specified 
databaseURL and is from the correct project.
```

But I got all the settings information on my own console in firebase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem.  In my case, it turned out that the underlying cause was that my service account was not a member of the "Editor" role of my project.  I had to go to the Google Cloud IAM console (go to the Firebase project console, click on the gear, and click on "Permissions") and create a new service account.

Apparently there was a Firebase bug where some service accounts were created with insufficient permissions. Here is a thread on Google Groups discussing the bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/i2sqxJIRzno

Comment: thanks, i had to create another account to have permissions corretly.

Comment: Re-creating the service account and assigning the "Editor Role" solved it.

Comment: @alissonoliveira if you're happy with the answer, you need to accept it